# JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCase stopped working in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, jsondecoder

After upgrading to Xcode 11/iOS 13, unit tests that previously worked are failing because the `JSONDecoder` is complaining that expected keys are missing.

The JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
{
  "documentation_url": "http://www.discogs.com/developers/",
  "statistics": {
    "labels": 1420380,
    "releases": 11630155,
    "artists": 6465084
  },
  "hello": "Welcome to the Discogs API.",
  "api_version": "v2"
}
```

The type that I'm trying to decode:

```
public struct DiscogsInfo: Codable {
    public var apiVersion: String?
    public var documentationUrl: URL
    public var hello: String
    public var statistics: Stats

    public struct Stats: Codable {
        public var labels: Int
        public var artists: Int
        public var releases: Int
    } 
}
```

The error:

```
(lldb) po error
▿ JSONErr
  ▿ parseFailed : 1 element
    ▿ error : DecodingError
      ▿ keyNotFound : 2 elements
        - .0 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "documentationUrl", intValue: nil)
        ▿ .1 : Context
          - codingPath : 0 elements
          - debugDescription : "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"documentationUrl\", intValue: nil) (\"documentationUrl\")."
          - underlyingError : nil
```

And the decoder:

```
(lldb) po jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy
Foundation.JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy.convertFromSnakeCase
```

The only thing I can think of is that iOS 13 somehow ignores the `keyDecodingStrategy`.

Comment: As far as I tested, `.convertFromSnakeCase` works as expected and the example JSON is decoded to `DiscogsInfo` without error. There may be something wrong where you are not showing.

Comment: You're quite right--the decoder that I configured to use `.convertFromSnakeCase` was getting replaced by one that had the default key decoder. Thanks for giving me a sanity check, though!